# How to handle solr delta-import in file based datasource

Tags: solr

I am trying to implement delta-import in solr indexing its working fine,in case when i am indexing data from database.But i want to implement it on filebased datasource.

My data-config.xml file is like 
dataSource type="com.solr.datasource.DataSource" name="SuggestionsFile"/>

```
<document name="suggester">
    <entity name="file" dataSource="SuggestionsFile">
        <field column="suggestion" name="suggestion" />
   </entity>
```

and i am using DataImportHandler in solrconfig.xml file.i am not able to post my config file,i tried to post,but i don't know why not its showing.

My DataSource class read the text file and return list of data,that solr index .Its working fine in case of full-import but not working in case of delta-import.Pls suggest what else i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The FileDataSourceEntityProcessor supports filtering the list based on the "newerThan" attribute:

```
<entity
    name="fileimport"
    processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
    newerThan="${dataimporter.last_index_time}"
    .. other options ..
>
    ...
</entity>
```

There's a [complete example](http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Sample-Solr-DataImportHandler-for-XML-Files.aspx) available online.